# He has been in the bathroom for two hours vs. Is in the bathroom for two hours

Tags: present-continuous

Which one is correct if I want to mention that he has taken two hours and hasn't come out yet?

1. "He is in the bathroom for two hours."
2. "He has been in the bathroom for two hours."
3. "It has been two hours since he went to the bathroom."

Comment: If you actually understand how the meaning is changed in your third option then I don’t see how you would deem that “more appropriate”

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct. The first is just incorrect and the third does not imply that he is still inside the bathroom.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is correct, the third one means that he hasn`t been to the bathroom for 2 hours.

Comment: what is wrong with my answer?